# How do I get a Jenkins server to push bash code to a different server?

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins

I have Jenkins installed on a Linux server.  It can run builds on itself.  I want to create either a Freestyle Project or an External Job that transfers a bash script and runs it on two separate linux servers.  Where in the GUI do I configure the destination server when I create a build?  I have added "nodes" in the GUI. I can see the free space of the servers in the Jenkins GUI, so I know the credentials work.  But when I create a build, I see no field that would tell Jenkins to push the bash scripts and run them on certain servers.

Are Jenkins nodes just servers that lend computing power to the master server?  Or are they the targets of Jenkins builds?  I believe that Jenkins "slaves" provide computing power to the Jenkins master server.

Normally Jenkins is used to integrate code.  What do you call the servers that Jenkins pushes code into?  They would be called Chef clients or Puppet agents if I was using Chef or Puppet for integrating code.  I've been doing my own research, but I don't seem to know the specific vocabulary.

Comment: The main remaining question I have is where in the GUI do I configure the destination server when I create a build?

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with such tools for several years. And for as far as I know there isn't a [Ubiquitous Language](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UbiquitousLanguage.html) for this.

The node's you can configure in Jenkins itself to add 'computing power' are indeed called build slaves.

Usually, external machines you will copy to, deploy to or otherwise use in jobs are called "target machine". As it will be the target of an action in your job.

Nodes can be used in several forms, you can use agents, which will require a small installation on the node machine. Which will create a running agent service with which Jenkins can communicate.

Another way is simply allow Jenkins to connect to a machine via ssh and let it execute commands there. Both are called nodes and could be called build slaves. But the first are usually dedicated nodes while the second can be any kind of machine as long as the ssh user can execute the build.

I also have not found any different terms for these two types.

It's probably not a real answer to your questions, but I do hope it helped.